# ASP.NET MVC View can't see member of an anonymous object viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an anonymous object view model with one member being from the Models folder, and another being from my own custom classes folder:

```
var viewModel = new {
    test1 = new Models.Test1(),
    test2 = new Classes.Test2()
};

return View(viewModel);
```

In the view, `@Model`, if you pause/breakpoint, and inspect it with the Visual Studio debugger, contains:

Model [press enter]:

```
{ Test1 = {MVC_Test1.Models.Test1}, Test2 = {MVC_Test1.Classes.Test2} }
    Test1: {MVC_Test1.Models.Test1}
    Test2: {MVC_Test1.Classes.Test2}
```

However, if you try the following:

Model.Test1 [press enter]

> 'Model.Test1' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'
> Message: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Test1'"

What is wrong? Is there a way to refer to a dynamically created view model done this way? Or must I explicitly create a class that instantiates `Models.Test1()` and `Classes.Test2()` into one class, and use that instead of the anonymous object?

Comment: What is the model declaration at the top of the view? @model.????, and is there any reason you do not want a strongly typed class being passed to the view?

Comment: Not really.  Just trying to reduce the codebase size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no sense in anonymous model for view, since you will have to create a anomymous input controls, so create a real typed view model

`````
public class ViewModel
{   
public Test1 Test1 {get; set;}
public Test2 Test2 {get; set;}  
};

model  = new ViewModel {
    test1 = new Models.Test1(),
    test2 = new Classes.Test2()
};

return View(model);
````
`````

Comment: Thanks.  That is in fact what I eventually did.  Was hoping to not have to create classes strictly to work with data in a view model, but, it's really more work that way in the long run.  I ended up making proper classes, and it works.  As I mentioned in another comment, I was just hoping to reduce codebase size and not have to create classes that serve no purpose other than just being populated and passed to a view.

Comment: Plus, I get intellisense that way, too.  ;-)